# Last insert id issue--How to fetch it

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm using `$id = mysqli_insert_id($connection);` to get the last inserted id, but in case if it updates any record in the table, it returns `0` as last inserted id.

Is there any way to handle this?

I want to get id each time weather it's inserting or updating.

Thanks

**Edit**

I need this id to be used for inserting data into `table2`

`id from tab1`
put data into `tab2` where `id` from `tab1` is `FK`

and most important, I'm not using the `update` with `where clause`

Here is my `code` that I'm using

```
  $val  = utf8_encode($val);
        mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf8');
        mysqli_query($connection, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        mysqli_query($connection, "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;");
        $sql = "INSERT INTO leaks($insert) VALUES($val)";

        $sql .= " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `url` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$data['url'])."';";
        mysqli_query($connection, ($sql))or die(mysqli_error($connection)."<br />".print($sql));
        $id = mysqli_insert_id($connection);
        $proofs['leaks_id'] = $id;
        mysqli_query($connection, "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;");
        print_r($id);
        $this->insertProofs($connection, $proofs);
        connection::close_connection($connection);
```

Please note down that `$this->insertProofs($connection, $proofs);` `inserts` data to  `table2` on the base of `key` passed to it

Comment: If you're updating, surely you know what `id` you're updating beforehand? And on insert, `mysqli_insert_id` is fine.

Comment: mysqli_insert_id dosen't work on update, and if you're updating you know to start with what id you update?

Comment: Why not get the id of the record while updating the record?

Comment: is id AUTO_INCREMENT attribute?

Comment: Yes I did, but in that case I'm unable to add data into secondary table

Comment: So the question boils down to obtaining `id` of records that have been updated?

Comment: Great, now after you've shed some light on the **whole** problem - why don't you simply create an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger, then you avoid the whole problem with fetching `id`s of updated records? Also, disabling foreign key checks.. are you sure you're doing things right? May I suggest asking a new question where you describe what you want to achieve, what you came up with and what you need it to do?

Comment: yes because without disabling foreign key checks it inserts fine, but when you update some record it issues error

Comment: and I want to insert data into second table based on the key returned from the table1

Comment: Right, it appears you're quite unaware of how things work. I've a feeling it's better that I retreat silently here and wish you good luck with solving your problem(s) with databases and PHP.

Comment: @N.B well, I'm going to use Triggers

Answer (score 2):

#### On `INSERT`

After executing an `INSERT` query, using [**`mysqli_insert_id()`**](https://www.php.net/mysqli_insert_id) is absolutely fine.

#### On `UPDATE`

Depending on your update, you;

- Would know the `id`'s you're updating
- Know the criteria to search for the `id`'s from the update.

For example, if your `UPDATE` was something like;

```
UPDATE `foo` SET `x`='y' WHERE `a`='b'
```

You can then run

```
SELECT `id` FROM `foo` WHERE `a`='b'
```

to fetch the updated id's.

### Edit

I see you're using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

You can modify your query to become (assuming `id` is the primary auto_increment key)

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
       `url` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$data['url'])."', 
       id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id)
```

Then you can use [**`mysqli_insert_id()`**](https://www.php.net/mysqli_insert_id) regardless of if it was an `UPDATE` or `INSERT`

For example, if I run (with a record of `id=2` exists; so we'll `update`);

```
INSERT INTO foobar (id, foo) VALUES (2, 'bar') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE foo = 'baz', id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

The output is `2`, as that was the last insert id.

Comment: That is wrong! There could have been such that have not been updated because they had the value 'b' set before!
In your example you could get more rows than actually have been updated in the operation.

Comment: No. My queries are [exactly the same as yours](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26733507/3000179) in the terms of the `WHERE` clause being the same.

Comment: Consider that there have been rows where a=b holds and ALSO x=y. This rows will not get updated. They will just stay the same.
So if he really wants to know those which have been changed/updated in the operation you have to do the find first and check where x is not yet equal to y

Comment: Yes, you are right. My SELECT missed the second condition too. Please take a look again.

Comment: I think you messed up things a bit,
I'm going to post the full query builder here, wait---